# Fetch 2 different CloudFirestore collection in the same file flutter using Futurebuilder

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Into my file I need to retrieve 2 different collections from CloudFirestore.
The first collection,"influencerUser" have all the user data and I need to fetch some user data into my widget
Now I updated my code with 2 differents Future collections
but still I cant get them

My code to get it is:

```
Future<QuerySnapshot> getPosts() async {
    return await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('influencerPost').get();
  }

  Future<QuerySnapshot> getUsers() async {
    return await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('influencerUser').get();
  }
```

this is my build method:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 0),
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: Future.wait([getUsers(),getPosts()]),
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<QuerySnapshot>> snapshot) {
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 5, 4),
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: [
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                                  child: Text(
                                    snapshot.data????.,//WHAT TO WRITE TO GET COLELCTIONS NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

The method you wrote will look for collection **`influencerUser`** inside the collection **`influencerPost`**, which as not found will return `null`.

You have to make two separate requests to get those 2 collections like this:

```
Future<QuerySnapshot> getPosts() async {
    return await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('influencerPost')
        .get();
}

Future<QuerySnapshot> getUsers() async {
    return await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('influencerUser')
        .get();
}
```

You can then wait for these  futures in your FutureBuilder like this:

```
FutureBuilder(
    future: Future.wait([getPosts(), getUsers()]),
    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<QuerySnapshot>> snapshot) {
       // The snapshot.data is of type List<QuerySnapshot>
       QuerySnapshot posts = snapshot.data[0]; // Result of getPosts()
       QuerySnapshot users = snapshot.data[1]; // Result of getUsers()
    }
);
```

Comment: ok but how to call getPosts and getUSers in the same futurebuilder?

Comment: @EmanuelDeveloper Updated the answer. Please check.

Comment: I get now this: The getter 'docs' isn't defined for the type 'List<QuerySnapshot>'.

Comment: I updated the code but still I cant get the Fields correctly.

Comment: @EmanuelDeveloper the `snapshot.data` is of type `List<QuerySnapshot>`, which contain list of results for the list of futures you mentioned in the same order. Check the code in updated answer.

Comment: ok but how I have to call for example content of TEXT(snapshot.......)

Comment: @EmanuelDeveloper It depends on the type and structure of the data you are storing on your database. Please refer to the documentation - https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries

Comment: it is very symple:
colelction name is influencerUser and document is imageUrl or firstName